# Wordpress thumbnail images are blurry

Tags: wordpress, hosting

My Wordpress site http://aapnabihar.com/ is having a problem from the last few days. The thumbnail images of the latest posts on the home page have blurry images. When I open the post, the images look fine in the post viewer. I have tried rebuilding thumbnail and setting thumbnail size from current 150x to 300x to 500x but nothing happens. Also, at the backend, whenever I'm opening any post, the CPU usages reaches upto 80% (I got a 16 GB RAM and 6 Core i5 processor CPU for the hosting).

I've uploaded a screenshot of the homepage.

[image]

Comment: in your stylesheet on line 2115, you have blur on `.mt-post-image-background` Removing this, will fix your plane image etc. the other images are way to small to be used here they are only 15px x 8px.

Comment: you might be using the wrong image size for those, because you also have them in larger sizes in the code. just not being displayed

Answer (score 0):

This seems lazy load has js error. Lazy load is not working properly. You must have to fix this however your image ratio is fine but not optimized.